# How can I set expiration time for Big Query table?

Tags: google-bigquery

When I'm loading or save query to table,
Is it possible to set up table expiration time with BQ command line tool ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set the expiration time on an existing BigQuery table using command line:

```
bq update --expiration 3600 mydataset.mytable
```

This example sets the expiration time of mytable in mydataset to 1 hour from now (3600 seconds). You can also specify "0" to remove existing expiration from your table.

Another way of doing this is by setting default expiration on a dataset. Every new table you create in this dataset will have the expiration time according to the setting. An example:

```
bq update --default_table_expiration 3600 mydataset
```

Every new table created in `mydataset` will only be available for one hour before it expires automatically.